# Query does not work when innerJoin and orderBy are used together in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am creating a query to find post list in nestjs(db=postgresql).

But, a syntax error occurs when orderBy is used after joining with the other table.

```
let qb = this.dataSource.manager
      .createQueryBuilder(Post, 'p')
      .addSelect((qb) => {
        return qb
          .select('COUNT(cpl.post_id)')
          .from(PostLike, 'cpl')
          .where('cpl.post_id = p.post_id');
      }, 'likesCount')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('p.author_data', 'u') <-- error!
      .skip((page - 1) * take)
      .take(take)
      .orderBy('"likesCount"', 'DESC').addOrderBy('p.reg_date', 'DESC')
      .getMany();
```

```
syntax error at or near ","
```

When i remove innerJoinAndSelect it works fine.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I thought typeorm didn't support this, so it was inefficient, but I solved it by running the query twice.

If you have any other better ideas, please share.